# Can I reference two functions in routes for a single blade in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: controller, routes, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Is it possible to reference two functions from my controller in my routes going to my view. Here is what I have:

My Routes

> Route::get('/list-of-staffs', ['as' => 'listofstaffs', 'uses' => 'User\MasterlistController@listofstaffsTable']);
>   Route::get('/list-of-staffs', ['as' => 'listofstaffs', 'uses' => 'User\MasterlistController@summaryOfstaffsTable']);

Is there a proper way to do this?

---

@Rodrane, here are my codes:

Controller:
public function listofstaffsTable()
    {

```
    $staffs = DB::table('staff_profiles')
        ->select('id','last_name','first_name','middle_name','name_ext','birthday','encoded_by')
        ->orderBy('last_name','ASC')            
        ->get();            

    $count = $staffs->count();

    $searchresults = ""; // define the searchresults variable       

    $i = 1;     

    foreach( $staffs as $key => $profile ) {

        $category = GetCategory::show($profile->id);
        $getcurrentklc = staffshipHistory::where('profile_id', '=', $profile->id)
                            ->orderBy('effective_date', 'DESC')                                                         
                            ->first(); // get the current klc from the most recent staffship history entry

                if( $getcurrentklc == null )
                {
                    $currentklc = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    $currentklc = $getcurrentklc->congregation_name;
                }       


        $getmemtype = staffshipHistory::where('profile_id', '=', $profile->id)
                            ->orderBy('effective_date', 'DESC')                                                         
                            ->first(); // get the current klc from the most recent staffship history entry

                if( $getmemtype == null )
                {
                    $memtype = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    $memtype = $getmemtype->staffship_type;
                }

        $getdatebaptized = staffshipHistory::where('profile_id', '=', $profile->id)
                            ->where('log_reason', '=', 'New staff')
                            ->orderBy('effective_date', 'DESC')                                                         
                            ->first(); // get the current klc from the most recent staffship history entry

                if( $getdatebaptized == null )
                {
                    $datebaptized = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    $datebaptized = $getdatebaptized->effective_date;
                }

        $getmotherinspirit1 = staffshipHistory::where('profile_id', '=', $profile->id)                              
                            ->where('log_reason', '=', 'New staff')
                            ->orderBy('effective_date', 'DESC')                                                         
                            ->first(); // get the current klc from the most recent staffship history entry

                if( $getmotherinspirit1 == null )
                {
                    $motherinspirit1 = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    $motherinspirit1 = $getmotherinspirit1->mother_spirit_1_name;
                }

        $getmemstatus = staffshipHistory::where('profile_id', '=', $profile->id)
                            ->orderBy('effective_date', 'DESC')                                                         
                            ->first(); // get the current klc from the most recent staffship history entry

                if( $getmemstatus == null )
                {
                    $memstatus = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    $memstatus = $getmemstatus->staffship_status;
                }           

        $searchresults .= '<tr>'.                                                                                      
                           '<td>'. $i .'</td>'.
                           '<td><a href="'. URL::route('viewstaffprofile', $profile->id) .'">'. $profile->last_name .' '. $profile->first_name .' '. $profile->middle_name .' '. $profile->name_ext .' </a></td>'.                                 
                           '<td>'. $currentklc .'</td>'.
                           '<td>'. $category .'</td>'.
                           '<td>'. $memtype .'</td>'.
                           '<td>'. $memstatus .'</td>'.                
                           '<td>'. $datebaptized .'</td>'.                 
                           '<td>'. $motherinspirit1 .'</td>'.
                           '<td>'. $profile->encoded_by .'</td>'.
                           '</tr>';
                           $i++;
    }


    $data = [];     
    $data['searchresults'] = $searchresults;    
    $data['staffCount'] = $count;

    return view( 'user/masterlist/list-of-staffs', $data);  

}
```

This is my blade

```
        {!! $staffCount !!}                                 
        <hr>
        <div class="page-header" style="text-align:center;">
          <h3 class="pageHeader">
            List of staffs
            <br>
          </h3>
        </div>          
        <div class="row">           
            <table class="table table-bordered" style="text-align: left;">
                    <tr>                            
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Full Name (Last, First, Middle)</th>                            
                        <th>KLC</th>
                        <th>Category</th>
                        <th>Mem Type</th>
                        <th>Mem Status</th>                         
                        <th>Date Baptized</th>
                        <th>Mother in Spirit</th>
                        <th>Encoder</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tbody>
                        {!! $searchresults !!}
                    </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Please see my files below. 
This works fine:

> {!! $searchresults !!}

But this gives me the error 'Call to a member function count() on array'

> {!! $staffCount !!}

Could you help me on this?

Comment: can I ask why you doing this ?

Comment: @Rodrane Sure, actually, I'm having a hard time trying to use more than one variable in a single blade, that's why I thought of creating another blade or view. I know that's stupid. Maybe you can help me. Let me post my codes above

Comment: @Rodrane I have updated the post above

Comment: you are not having problem with passing data I think you dont have a correct data probably something on this line  `$count = $staffs->count();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this already. Looks like a code that I missed

Comment: I strongly recommend you to elaborate on what code that you missed and what you did to solve your problem. Otherwise, this answer is not really useful for future readers of this post. Thank you.